# Pintar las filas de un JTable segun una condicion - Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un JTable tbDocTransferir con 17 columnas llena de información, lo que quiero es pintar cada fila que cumpla con la siguiente condición: si en la primera columna de las filas del JTable dice "E" se pinte de rojo y si no dice nada se pinte de Negro. He estado intentando con este codigo pero al momento que ejecuto no se cambia.

```
void pintarFila(){
        String fila;
        for(int i=0; i<tbDocTransferir.getRowCount(); i++){
            fila = ""+tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 0);
            if (fila == "E")
                tbDocTransferir.setForeground(Color.RED);
            else if (fila == " ")
                tbDocTransferir.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deseas pintar la **Fila** de tu JTable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Crea una clase nueva que herede de **DefaultTableCellRenderer** para que maneje el render de tus celdas.

```
package ejemplo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;


public class RowsRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
private int columna ;

public RowsRenderer(int Colpatron)
{
    this.columna = Colpatron;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column)
{        
    setBackground(Color.white);
    table.setForeground(Color.black);
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
    if(table.getValueAt(row,columna).equals("A"))
    {
        this.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }else if(table.getValueAt(row,columna).equals("B")){
        this.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }else if(table.getValueAt(row, columna).equals("C")){
        this.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    return this;
  }
  }
```

Clase main del ejemplo:

```
package ejemplo;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class JPanelDemo extends JFrame {
private String columnas[] = {"Auto", "Color", "Tipo"};
private Object celdas[][] = {{"Kia","Rojo", "C"},
    {"Toyota","Azul","C"},
    {"Lexus","Negro","B"},
    {"BMW","Verde","B"},
    {"Pagani", "Dorado", "A"},
    {"Ferrari", "Rojo", "A"}
};
private JTable tabla;

public JPanelDemo(){
    super("JTable Color");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    tabla = new JTable(celdas,columnas);
    RowsRenderer rr = new RowsRenderer(2);
    tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, rr);
    add(new JScrollPane(tabla));
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    JPanelDemo obj = new JPanelDemo();
}

}
```

- Si el auto es de tipo C, entonces el texto de la fila se pintara en
  Verde.
- Si el auto es de tipo B, entonces el texto de la fila se pintara de Azul.
- Si el auto es de tipo A, entonces el texto de la fila se pintara de Rojo.

Answer (score 0):

Funciona muy bien, fácil de utilizar, en mi método para la tabla solo añadí esta parte

```
RowsRenderer rr = new RowsRenderer(2); --------->Este 2 es el que indica es la pocisión de columna donde se hará la condición
tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, rr);
```

Y cree completa la clase RowsRenderer así tal cual la pusiste, muchas gracias.